# Display name and s_no

Tags: android, listview

```
Cursor cur = acc.query("details", new String[] { "name"}, null,
            null, null, null, null);

    cur.moveToFirst();
    listContent = new String[cur.getCount()];
    for (i = 0; i < cur.getCount(); i++) {
        String ss1;
        ss1 = cur.getString(0);
        listContent[i] = ss1;

        cur.moveToNext();
    }
    cur.close();
```

Comment: Be more detailed, explain better what you want to do

Comment: What is an s_no in relation to this code? What is a name in relation to this code. This query to "details" is not known by us so you need to define the fields better or we cannot help you.

Comment: @user1742971 check demo.....   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338131/exception-while-retriving-data-from-the-sqlitedatabase/12853460#12853460

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try as:

```
Cursor cur = acc.query("details", new String[] { "name"}, null,
        null, null, null, null);
listContent = new String[cur.getCount()];
int i=0;
while(cur.moveToNext()) {
    listContent[i] =cur.getString(0);
     i++;
}
cur.close();
```

and easy way to do same without using any index counter use ArrayList instead of Array as :

```
Cursor cur = acc.query("details", new String[] { "name"}, null,
        null, null, null, null);
 List<String> strArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

while(cur.moveToNext()) {
    strArrayList.add(cur.getString(0));
}
cur.close();
```